Creating rings with buffer as polygon in QGIS
I need to draw circles with a buffer in one view. It will be an area around cities. I think it can be solved with a buffer or a cutout from the circle.
How can I do this?


If you have a layer with points, you can create two buffers and use difference between the first one with the second one in the following way:

Buffer at 10 meters.



Buffer at 5 meters.



Use the tool Difference using the buffers previously created.


Result:

Note: All the tools you can find it on the right menu (Processing Toolbox)

Thank you very much! Beauty in simplicity. Exactly what I need. Thank you

You are welcome, I am glad that it works for you  :) @MarekDrličiak

Same logic as Jhon's but using an expression:
difference(buffer(geometry:=$geometry, distance:=200), 
buffer(geometry:=$geometry, distance:=100))

If you just want the symbol you can add a Geometry Generator symbol layer:

If you want to create a separate polygon layer use Geometry by expression
